# What is the best strategie to parallelize development with GWT?

Tags: gwt

I will need to build some complex GUI (approx a 100 of views). So we need to parallelize the development as much as possible (maybe on 10 devs). One option is to develop with html, css (compass) and JQuery+plugin in a classic way. We know exactly how to do and there is no question about that.

The other option is to use GWT, but we worried about how much development is parallelizable with GWT. We want to massively use Ajax and our 100 views will be hosted on 5 pages max.

Any experience return with such concern will be greatly appreciated.

JM.

Answer (score 7):

**GWT is great for parallel development but beware of the learning curve !**

IMO GWT is more for OO developpers to write UI code than for Js developpers.

Java (like many other OO languages) allows you to split classes in many little files, allowing many people to work on the project simultaneously. Design patterns can help you factor complex programming patterns into reusable blocks. Most used patterns with GWT are MVP (an alternative version of MVC), Observer (with the eventBus), Command (with [gwt-dispatch](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/)), ... Besides you can also use things like dependency injection with [Gin](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) so that modules can be composed easily, based on their interface (being implemented or not).

So GWT is great for Java developpers. They can use pattern they (should) master, and they (most of the time) don't have to worry about browser-specific details or Javascript.

A lot of developpers with a JavaScript background have a tendency, at least in the beginning, to code in Java as if it were JavaScript. The style is different and it takes a lot of time to be able to produce well-designed Java code, not too mention GWT where patterns and GWT-specific design are crucial and not always well documented. Anybody can write in Java, but the tens of books and billions of crappy lines of code around clearly indicate that it is not so easy to produce **good** OO code.

**The same goes for Js.** Put a Java developper on a Js project and watch the code being messed up within hours.

As Rod Johnson (father of Spring framework) says in his great book [expert one on one j2ee design and development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764543857), when choosing a technology you should make a decision based on the skills you have !

**So if I had a killer team with Javascript, HTML and CSS, who has limited knowledge about the above patterns or Java, I would tell them to learn about Ember (if they don't know it already) or any other Javascript MVC framework which also facilitates parallel development, buy books like "Maintainable JavaScript" or "Javascript patterns", and have everybody continue to do what they do best.**

If the team is motivated by a new tech and wants to try GWT, I would put one or two of them on a proof-of-concept for at least a month. If they feel comfortable with GWT I would hire the best GWT consultant around, have him check once a week that we use the right tools and the right patterns in the right place, and have the team embrace GWT. I'd at least budgetize **3 to 6 months for everybody to get up to speed**, depending on their knowledge of Java and the above patterns.

Here is my own experience.

We hired two medior consultants with no GWT background for a one-year project with 6 people who had a background in procedural programmation for half of them and in plain not-too-fancy Java for the other half.

The consultants behaved as if it was a payed self-training opportunity. Most design decision where taken by outsourced people and the team didn't have a chance to make his own mistakes and learn from them. At the moment (one year later) everybody improved but we are still struggling with the patterns, tools and design problems. It took me one month to read the GWT doc and two books about the subject but at least 4 months of hands-on dev to start figuring out I was wrong in many places. I learn new stuff about GWT every day and discover new bad design decisions we made every two other week.

Answer (score 1):

With GWT, you can use the MVP design pattern, which separate your screen in small views and presenter. Instead the common socle and navigation is created, you can work each devs on a independant view.
The documentation of GWT :
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html

I hope I answer your response.

Comment: GWTP & mvp4g are frameworks designed over GWT to easily follow the MVP pattern. They are of great help.